# Is there any possible condition where if exists ( select * from table ) is required?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL best practices says you should never use `SELECT *` with exists or not exists check. Exist just checks existence of any row therefore simply `IF (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE)` should do the job.

I am wondering if there could be any scenario where `SELECT *` is a must and `SELECT 1` can not replace it. I tried a scenario where table returns all NULL but in such case `IF EXISTS (SELECT *)` check returns TRUE therefore result remain same.

Comment: As far as SQL Server is concerned both statements are identical.

Comment: *"SQL best practices says you should never use SELECT * with exists"* it does? Where? With an `EXISTS` SQL Server doesn't actually "care" what's in the `SELECT`. Many just prefer `SELECT 1` as it's less ambiguous (some expect an `EXISTS` to fail, for example, if a `NULL` is returned, which isn't true), and can't be confused with an `IN`.

Comment: @Larnu so does it mean if select * is used with exists, SQL Server does not try to retrieve all fields even for 1 row?

Comment: No, it won't. It doesn't resolve the `SELECT` at all; it "short circuits" as soon as a single row is found.

Comment: Great, thanks all for quick responses.

Comment: Quite the contrary - I would argue the `IF EXISTS()` clause is the **only** place where a `SELECT *` is acceptable and doesn't cause any troubles ;-) SQL Server just checks for the existance of at least one row matching your `WHERE` clause - no columns are returned from the `SELECT *` statement ....

Comment: You can prove SQL Server doesn't care if it's `select *` or `select whatever` by using `if exists(select 1/0`... which works fine; there is no such "best practice" referring to `exists` and `select *`

Comment: _SQL best practices says ..._ It would be helpful to know where you found this information.

Comment: Unfortunately one experienced SQL developer told me this.  Also, as using select * (not with exists) is considered a bad practice, this made me believe that same logic applies when select * is used with exists. Does sql server also optimizes count(*) and it is same as using count(1)?

Comment: Of course SELECT COUNT(*) will be optimized exactly the same way as COUNT(1) because this does not count values, but rows... To convinct you, try SELECT COUNT(1/0)